Kill ElGamal ;-)
I think we should kill the elgamal tag (70 questions). It currently includes two mostly unrelated schemes. The schemes were invented by the same person and are both group based crypto, but I don't think that this justifies a shared tag.

ElGamal encryption, which currently doesn't have a dedicated tag
ElGamal signatures, which already have the tag elgamal-signature (10 questions)

How should we remove it?

Edit all elgamal questions to remove this tag and add one of the specific tags as necessary
Remove elgamal from the signature questions, then rename the tag to elgamal-encryption. This requires fewer edits, but has a higher risk of mistakes.

Related question: Should we have a tag for all of a specific cryptographer's inventions/contributions?

Related but separate question: Is the hashed-elgamal tag worthwhile? If yes, what should its wiki description be?

I just retagged a couple of question which did not have the [tag:elgamal-signature] tag but are clearly about signatures. I also removed the tags from a couple of questions where ElGamal was only incidental to the actual question.

Update: I believe that all remaining [ElGamal] questions are about encryption, though some are a bit unclear so I'm not completely sure.

I'd go for change ElGamal to elgamal-encryption.

The rename sounds good to me. If any signature questions end up caught in it, we can always retag them afterwards.

I went ahead and performed the changes discussed in the comments. In other words, I renamed elgamal as elgamal-encryption.
